# Web extension - alternative to notification with button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a web extension that lets any website access the clipboard. On request I will ask the user if it is okay to give access to the clipboard.
I do this in two ways

1. I create a notification

The problem: firefox doesn't allow buttons, so in the message I say "Click here to allow website x access". I added an eventlistener to the notification that sends a message back to the content script and it proceeds from there. It's okay but not really the best solution (I want buttons)

2. As a fallback I have a simple confirm box.

The problem: it doesn't really look good.

Now my other idea is to create a custom confirm box. That means create some html, css and javascript and append it to the DOM. This although is potentionally dangerous as websites can just trigger a "click" on the "allow access"-button then.

So I am basically looking for a nice and safe way to get confirmation from the user.
So what next? iframes? Is it possible to include an html page from the addon with access to a content script in an iframe?

Or is there some other way I can implement this maybe web extensions already offer something like this?

Comment: This is really too broad for Stack Overflow, as there are multiple ways to accomplish this.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind would be to have the extension open an HTML page from within the extension in a separate window which is asks for the confirm. The HTML would then be complete separate from the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely overlooked the click event argument. There is a event.isTrusted property which is false when the event was triggered.  (maybe not available in all browsers). But this pretty much solves the issue.